# How do I set a node/page's background image to that content's image?

Tags: 7, media

I've installed both 'Background Image' and 'Dynamic Background' but am having trouble trying to configure them for my situation. In the website I am trying to edit, there are content types of 'Performer,' 'Venue' among others. Now each content type has an image as one of their fields and I would like to have that image as the background image for that content's page.

Background Image only gives me option to do this for 1 content type, and when I tried setting it up, nothing appears.

I'm pretty sure I could do this with Dynamic Background, but the process would be really inefficient; I would have to add the pictures again to Dynamic Background's library.

So is there another way to do this? Or what can I do with Background Image to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without installing extra modules:

1. Add an image field in the content types you want to enable a dynamic background image.
2. Use this code:
   template.php:

   ```
   function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
       if (!empty($vars['node'])) {
           $node = $vars['node'];
           if (!empty($node->field_background_image)) {
               $image = file_create_url($node->field_background_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']);
               $vars['background_image_css'] = 'style="background: url(' . $image . ') no-repeat scroll center center / cover #FCFCFC;"';
           }
   }
   }
   ```

Add this in your div#content in page.tpl.php:

`print (!empty($background_image_css)) ? $background_image_css : ''; ?>`

Updated version: template.php:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 $node = menu_get_object('node');
 if (!empty($node) && !empty($node->field_background_image)) { 
        $image = file_create_url($node->field_background_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']); 
        drupal_add_css('div#content {background: url(' . $image . ') no-repeat scroll center center / cover #FCFCFC; }', array('type' => 'inline'));
 } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, but better to use `hook_preprocess_html`, `menu_get_object('node')` and `drupal_add_css` to add the CSS properly instead

Comment: Falco - your solution worked for me except in one case where I published a piece of content and set it 'promote to front page'. It seems to fail on this - !empty($node), where node is initialized with this - $node = menu_get_object('node'); - as per your code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Background Image](http://drupal.org/project/bg_image) is using a content-type as some kind of interface for "global" background-images. So if you want to tie your backgrounds to nodes, i recommend the [BackgroundField](http://drupal.org/project/backgroundfield) module.

> BackgroundField started as an extension of the CCK ImageField that allows a CSS selector and background attributes to be set for a content-type. This is particularly helpful for allowing your node authors to add images to a node that are integrated into the theme of the site. With the inclusion of the Image field in Drupal 7, BackgroundField was rewritten to extend that core functionality.

Comment: Thanks, BackgroundField seems to be the exact thing I need. Have you used it at all? I'm having trouble getting it to work and display the image I set as the background. Nothing shows up...

Comment: What have you done already? Don't forget to add a css class in the settings for the field of the image to which the image gets assigned.

Comment: Well, the content type or node already exists. I've tried using the module "Background Image" to set an image as the background, but nothing happens. I haven't tried using "Dynamic Background" because it seems very time consuming because the site will have a lot of pages/nodes. Any chance you could elaborate on what css class I should add? I haven't come across anything on Google suggesting a css class

Comment: This is pretty much how this conversation will be going: http://drupal.org/node/1824836  ;o)

Comment: Ha that is basically what I'm looking for, but my picture won't show up regardless of the CSS selector I choose. If I look at the page source, I don't see a URL that links to the image I'm trying to set as my background. And is the CSS selector based on what I put in my global.css file?